# How to verify if array contains sequential items on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a document on Mongo with the following structure, how do I verify if `data` array contains two or more properties with the same value, one after the other?

In this case, my goals is to point out that among all documents on a collection, this one have two statuses with the same value ("status_B").

I know how to count how many times a status occurs on `data` array, but I need to find in which documents two or more status occur sequentially.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("XYZ"),
    "data": [
        {
            "status": "status_A",
            "other": "data"
        },
        {
            "status": "status_B",
            "other": "data"
        },
        {
            "status": "status_B",
            "other": "data"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation checks if two consecutive `data` array elements have the same `status` value and prints those documents.

Using the following two ***sample documents***:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "status" : "status_A",
                        "other" : "data"
                },
                {
                        "status" : "status_B",
                        "other" : "data"
                },
                {
                        "status" : "status_B",
                        "other" : "data"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "status" : "status_B",
                        "other" : "data"
                },
                {
                        "status" : "status_A",
                        "other" : "data"
                },
                {
                        "status" : "status_B",
                        "other" : "data"
                }
        ]
}
```

The ***aggregation*** query:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: {
           matches: { 
               $reduce: {
                   input: "$data", 
                   initialValue: {  prev_status: "",  has_seq: false  },
                   in: {
                       $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$value.prev_status", "$$this.status" ] },
                                { has_seq: true, prev_status: "$$this.status" },
                                { has_seq: "$$value.is_seq", prev_status: "$$this.status" }
                       ]
                   }
               }
           }
      }
  },
  { 
      $match: { "matches.has_seq": true } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { matches: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

The ***result*** is the document with `_id: 1`, which has the consecutive array elements with `status: "status_B"`.

Answer (score 1):

`$map` and `$range` to the rescue.   Together they allow you to craft "for loops" on arrays.    Given an input set like this:

```
[
 {_id:0,
  "data": [
{ "status": "status_A", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_C", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_D", "other": "data" }
    ]
 }
 ,{_id:1,
  "data": [
{ "status": "status_A", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_X", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_X", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_B", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_D", "other": "data" },
{ "status": "status_D", "other": "data" }
    ]
 }
]
```

then this pipeline will identify where in the `data` array the `status` field is duped in the `n` and `n+1` item:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {dupe: {$map: {
                input: {$range:[0, {$add:[{$size:"$data"},-1]} ]},
                as: "z",
                in: {$cond: [ {$eq: [
// Important trick: $arrayElemAt[array,n] will give you the whole object at offset n.
// $arrayElemAt[arr plus dotpath into object, n] will give you just the field at the
// dotpath; in our case here, status is a single scalar string:
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", "$$z"]},
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", {$add:["$$z",1]} ]}
                                     ]},
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", "$$z"]},null]}
        }}
    }}
]);
```

to yield:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "dupe" : [ null, null, null ] }
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "dupe" : [
        null,
        null,
        "status_B",
        "status_B",
        null,
        null,
        "status_B",
        null,
        "status_D"
    ]
}
```

Some may find the pipeline easier by setting variables with `$let`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {dupe: {$map: {
                input: {$range:[0, {$add:[{$size:"$data"},-1]} ]},
                as: "z",
                in: {$let: {
                  vars: { n0: {$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", "$$z"]},
                          n1: {$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", {$add:["$$z",1]} ]}
                  },
                  in: {$cond: [ {$eq: [ "$$n0", "$$n1" ]}, "$$n0", null ]}
            }}
        }}
    }}
]);
```

If you want a simpler result that tells if any status is n/n+1 duped for any number of times, use `$anyElementTrue` to get a simple boolean output:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {dupe: {$anyElementTrue: { $map: {
                input: {$range:[0, {$add:[{$size:"$data"},-1]} ]},
                as: "z",
                in: {$cond: [ {$eq: [
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", "$$z"]},
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", {$add:["$$z",1]} ]}
                                     ]},
{$arrayElemAt: ["$data.status", "$$z"]},null]}
                    }}
        }
    }}
]);
```

to yield:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "dupe" : false }
{ "_id" : 1, "dupe" : true }
```